# multiple return statements in python "def" causes syntax error

Tags: python

I'm trying to test my function "def" in a python shell, but when i paste it in there are errors.  It seems not to like it when i have multiple return statements inside one "def".
 For example:

```
def foo():
valid = True
if valid:
   return True
return False
```

Does anyone know why?

thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? That will tell us a lot. Although, if your code example is completely accurate then you're missing indentation on the function body.

Comment: "It seems not to like it"?  Are you guessing the interpreter's mood somehow?

Comment: You should immediately format your hard drive to save the human species! If your Python installation has acquired enough intelligence to 'like' and 'not like' stuff, then skynet is just around the corner! Do it now unless you want yourself and everybody you love to be enslaved! Or did you mean that you are getting a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: Is it possible to change the subject to 'Faulty indentation causes syntax error'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Should be this:

```
def foo():
    valid = True
    if valid:
        return True
    return False
```